# PHP Get From URL

Tags: php

I was wondering how I could remove a certain part of a url using PHP.

This is the exact url in questions:

http://www.mysite.com/link/go/**370768**/

I'm looking to remove the number ID into a variable.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you're looking for [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to alter your URL to something nicer.

Comment: Is your number ID always in the same position and does it always have 6 digits followed by a slash?

Comment: Maybe you can use this http://php.net/parse-url

Comment: do you use some kind of Framework or is there .htaccess file in your app route that rewrites the URL, there should be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many (many!) ways of extracting a number from a string. Here's an example which assumes the URL starts with the format like `http://www.mysite.com/link/go/<ID>` and extracts the ID.

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/link/go/370768/';
sscanf($url, 'http://www.mysite.com/link/go/%d', $id);
var_dump($id); // int(370768)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()`

```
print_r(explode("/", $url));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using some kind of framework. There are two ways to check the [**$_GET**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variables:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

or check the manual of the manual of the framework and see how the GET/POST is passed internally, for example in CakePHP you have all parameters save internally in your controller you can access them like that:

```
$this->params['product_id'] or $this->params['pass']
```

There is another solution which is not very reliable and professional but might work:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$vars = explode('/', $path);
echo $vars[2];
```

$vars should contain array like this:

```
array (
  0 => link
  1 => go
  2 => 370768
)
```

Comment: you meaned get with URL in it?

Comment: $_GET is internall PHP array that contains all variables sent in the URL:  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) inside of your `.htaccess` to internally rewrite this URL to something more friendly for PHP (convert `/link/go/370768/` into `?link=370768`, for example).